# GitHub Actions - Paths Filter Not Working For CSharp Files

Tags: .net, github-actions, cicd

I'm building my first GitHub action workflow to run when I open or modify a PR. I want to achieve building my .NET Solution when C# files (`.cs`) are changed in commits (not `.md`, not `.js`).

My GitHub action (`dotnet-build.yaml`) fragment looks like :

```
name: Build SLN 

on:
  push:
    branches: ["develop"]
    paths:
      - "**.cs"
  pull_request:
    branches: ["develop"]
    paths:
      - "**.cs"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    ...
```

**The Problem:**
Even though I set up to only honor `.cs` files, the GitHub action runs, when I push up changesets/commits that include `.md` files or `.js`.

**Q)** What is wrong with my syntax?  And what can I do differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you expecting it to run only when the change touches exclusively `.cs` files? The behaviour is "if at least one file in the changeset matches, then run".

Comment: Yes, I am expecting the workflow to run when CS files change only.  I'm not sure what you mean with your quote yet. Can you assist @benjamin-w?https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w